# Link two TextFields so that they have the same content

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, letters, output, forms

I am trying to create a letter form in which the user has to fill out his address in the main body in TextFields. Is it possible to link the contents of these fields to a second field in the header of the document? What I am trying to achieve is that when the user enters his address in the body, the address will also automatically be written down in the header of the document in the output file as well (thus, the user only has to fill in his address once instead of twice).

In the main body I use the TextField command like this:

```
\TextField[name=Name, width=10cm,  bordercolor={red}, borderstyle=U, value={First Name Last Name}]{}
```

This field I want to link two a second field in the header such that when the user enters something in one field, it should automatically be filled in in the second field.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361269/hyperref-textfield-how-to-implement-an-hyperref-action-without-pushbutton

Comment: You can use a textfield in the header with the same name, it will then share the content with its sibling.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately, this did not work :(

Comment: Reverse question: [Is this a hyperref forms bug? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/is-this-a-hyperref-forms-bug)